# In Java, can you call a parent class's superclass constructor through the constructor of the child class of the parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I know the wording is a bit confusing and strange, but bear with me, I have no clue how to phrase that any shorter.

Say you have a class called `SuperBlah`, and you inherited it in a class called `Blah` then you inherited `Blah` into a class called `ChildBlah` (So `SuperBlah-Blah-ChildBlah`). Would  the `super();` keyword used in the `ChildBlah`'s constructor called the `SuperBlah`'s constructor if `Blah` doesn't have a constructor?

To those of you who said no, then why does this work?
We have a class called BlusterBug that extends Critter class, and calls the super in the BlusterBug's constructor. Critter doesn't have a constructor, but the Class that Critter extends does have a constructor. (I purposefully omitted the rest of the code on the classes)

```
public class BlusterCritter extends Critter {
    // instance vaiables
    private int courageFactor;
    private static final double DARKENING_FACTOR = 0.05;
    // create a constructor(include what is necesary for parent)
    public BlusterCritter(int c)
    {
        super();
        courageFactor = c;
    }
```

Then in the Critter class, it doesn't have any constructors!

```
public class Critter extends Actor// omitted all the code
{
    /**
     * A critter acts by getting a list of other actors, processing that list,
     * getting locations to move to, selecting one of them, and moving to the
     * selected location.
     */
    public void act()
    {
        if (getGrid() == null)
            return;
        ArrayList<Actor> actors = getActors();
        processActors(actors);
        ArrayList<Location> moveLocs = getMoveLocations();
        Location loc = selectMoveLocation(moveLocs);
        makeMove(loc);
    }
```

But then the Actor class has a constructor!

```
public class Actor
{
    private Grid<Actor> grid;
    private Location location;
    private int direction;
    private Color color;

    /**
     * Constructs a blue actor that is facing north.
     */
    public Actor()
    {
        color = Color.BLUE;
        direction = Location.NORTH;
        grid = null;
        location = null;
    }
```

And the weirdest part? The program works perfectly fine and the compiler doesn't do catch any errors! How is this happening?

Comment: This kind of question is really best answered by just writing the classes with print statements and testing. I think you could get your answer in less than 30 lines of code, and you could learn a lot of details.

Comment: **Every** Java class has at least one constructor. If it does not declare a constructor, it has a default constructor that takes no parameters and contains only a `super();` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Blah` doesn't have *any* constructor, the compiler will generate an implicit no-argument constructor for `Blah` that is just `super()`--that is, it will call `SuperBlah`'s constructor.

So when `ChildBlah`'s constructor calls `super()`, it will call this implicit constructor that the compiler generated for `Blah`, which results in `SuperBlah`'s constructor being called.  So in some sense, I think the answer to your question is "yes".

But this only works if `Blah` has no constructors.  (And in your actual code, `Critter` doesn't have any constructors, so it works.)  If any other constructors are defined for `Blah`, but there's no accessible no-argument constructor, then there won't be an implicit no-argument constructor, and the result will be an error at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't. It will call the implicit default constructor in `Blah`.
If `Blah` defines other constructors (with parameters) but has no
default constructor, then this will generate a compilation error.

Also, note that constructors are not inherited
(if that relates in any way to your question/thoughts).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. If `Blah` doesn't have any constructor, it will call default empty constructor and transitively it will call non-parametric `SuperBlah` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It will call Blah's constructor, throwing a compiler error if Blah doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0):

No. Constructors aren't like methods in the respect of optional overriding by an intermediate class in the hierarchy. If an instance method of the super class is not implemented in the intermediate class, calling the method from the subclass via `super.method()` will invoke the superclass method. But a constructor for every class in the hierarchy must be called - you can't skip over the intermediate class's constructors.